# How to not install recommended and suggested packages?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

I use Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit, I did the following: `sudo gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf` and added

```
APT::Install-Recommends "false";
APT::Install-Suggests "false";
```

But it did not work. When I try to install a package, it still wants to install the suggested and recommended packages. How can I solve this?

Comment: `apt-config dump |fgrep -i recommend` will suggest current fashion syntax in case it changes again.

Comment: Use `apt-mark hold package-that-apt-should-leave-alone`. *hold
           hold is used to mark a package as held back, which will prevent the package from being automatically
           installed, upgraded or removed.*

Answer (score 126, accepted):

If you do not want to install recomended packages:

- for `apt-get` use `--no-install-recommends` and `--no-install-suggests`
- for `aptitude` use `--without-recommends` or `-R`

---

If you want these flags to always be enabled (I do NOT recommend this) put the following lines in your `/etc/apt/apt.conf` file:

```
APT::Install-Recommends "false";
APT::Install-Suggests "false";
```

Remember that these packages are recommended for a reason and it is probably not a good idea to ignore it at all times. You would be better off using the flags in the cases where you know that the recommended packages are wrong.

Comment: Reading the packaging documentation I understand that 'recommended' packages should probably be installed. Can you explain why you don't recommend disabling the installation of 'suggested' packages? They seem rather annoying to me so far.

Comment: To add to this, the analogous command line flag to `--no-install-recommends` for suggested packages when running `apt-get install ...` is `--no-install-suggests`.

Answer (score 41):

According to me, changing conf files are too risky and unnecessary. Rather `apt-get` provides options to specify do not install recommended packages.

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends package-name
```

This is better than changing conf file.

Comment: it is your machine. there's no problem with configuring it as you see fit

Answer (score 34):

The correct syntax in recent versions appears to be:

```
APT::Install-Suggests "0";
APT::Install-Recommends "0";
```

You can put this in `/etc/apt/apt.conf` (which no longer exists by default) or in a file such as `99local` in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d`.

Watch out for any other files in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d` which may override your settings.

Answer (score 16):

Checked today (07 Jan 2015).

These settings work well for me:

```
APT::Install-Recommends "false";
APT::Install-Suggests "false";
```

This solution does not work:

```
APT::Get::Install-Recommends "false";
APT::Get::Install-Suggests "false";
```

Comment: The question is about 12.04. The answer from lan already mentions for later versions it is APT::Install-Recommends so your answer does not add additional information.

Answer (score 5):

You might be like me and have an `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99synaptic` file lurking around. I'm still not entirely sure where this file came from but it contains one line:

```
APT::Install-Recommends "true";
```

That would certainly have overridden a change in `/etc/apt/apt.conf`. I can't see that the file is used by any package any longer so I would suggest just deleting it (check the contents are similar) or swapping true for false.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify configuration strings from the command line, using the `-o` option.

This works for me (APT v.1.4.8) (`sudo` as needed):

```
apt-get install package1 package2 -o APT::Install-Suggests=0 -o APT::Install-Recommends=0
```

Comment: This works for `apt-get`. But what should I do for `apt`?

Answer (score 3):

Use the following command to add it to `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99norecommend`:

```
apt-config dump | grep -we Recommends -e Suggests | sed s/1/0/ | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99norecommend
```

Check the current settings by:

```
apt-config dump | grep -we Recommends -e Suggests
```

See: [Can I make apt-get always use --no-install-recommends?](https://superuser.com/q/615565/87805)

Comment: Small variation to this to handle true/false too:
`apt-config dump | grep -we Recommends -e Suggests | 's/1/0/;s/true/false/' | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99norecommend`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/60user file with the single line:

```
APT::Install-Recommends "false";
```

This works fine for me on 12.04.

Comment: OP already stated that this did not work.

Comment: I checked this on 10.04, 12.04, 14.04 and APT::GET::* dont work, buy APT::Install-* did work well with "apt-get install"