# How to modify settings in 'apt.conf' file that no longer exists in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, apt, configuration

I would like to add settings to the file `apt.conf` , but I realized that it was replaced by a folder called `etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`.

How can I configure with this new model?

Answer (score 13):

It is best to create your own user file in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d` so you can guarantee that it won't be overwritten by package updates. Rather than adding to existing files in the directory, create your own general file called `99mysettings`  with

```
sudo touch /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99mysettings
```

It is labelled with a `99` so that your settings are run last and so override any of the same values for the specified settings present in other files in the directory.

Then to edit your file run

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99mysettings
```

and then, for example, you could add the following (although not usually recommended) configuration item:

```
APT::Install-Suggests "true";
```

If you wanted apt to stop installing recommended packages (again not usually the best decision) you could use

```
APT::Install-Recommends "false";
```

The syntax of these commands differs to how the man page will describe how entries for the older `apt.conf` should be set up; **previously** `APT::GET::Install-Suggests "true";` would have been the syntax, but that will not work for the example above.

The man page will give you an indication of the general settings available, so please enter `man apt.conf` or see the [Ubuntu manpages online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man5/apt.conf.5.html). However, the best source for apt configuration settings is the Debian Handbook, available [here online](http://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.apt-get.html) or as a [complete pdf](http://debian-handbook.info/download/stable/debian-handbook.pdf) here, and it contains very useful information that is mostly applicable for Ubuntu as well.

Answer (score 2):

From versions newer than Gutsy, the file /etc/apt/apt.conf has been replaced by /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/proxy (create it if needed), with the same structure.

Answer (score 2):

Find the existing configuration by `apt-config dump` command, e.g.:

```
apt-config dump | grep -we Recommends -e Suggests
```

Change the values and add into `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99somefile` (a new file). The number before file gives priority (lower runs earlier, higher runs latest).

Here is the example [disabling `APT::Install-Recommends` and `APT::Install-Suggests`](https://askubuntu.com/q/179060/78223):

```
apt-config dump | grep -we Recommends -e Suggests | sed s/1/0/ | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99norecommend
```

Answer (score 1):

The `apt.conf` file which contains configuration for APT is by default located in `/etc/apt/`.

To check what's under `apt` directory, do the following in terminal:

```
cd /etc/apt
ls
```

The `apt.conf` file should be listed after the `ls` command.

*However*, if it does not exist, you can create it by running the following command:

```
gksu gedit apt.conf
```

(Make sure the present working directory is `/etc/apt`, if not, then `cd` to `/etc/apt` first.)

This will ask for your password and launch `gedit` allowing you to create your `apt.conf` file.

You can also use:

```
sudo nano apt.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create the file /etc/apt/apt.conf if you need it, and put in the stuff you want.

```
man apt.conf
```