# Why does LMMS depend on wine?

Tags: wine, dependencies, lmms

I was uninstalling wine, and I saw that it also uninstalled [LMMS](http://lmms.sourceforge.net/) at the same time. Thinking it was just something weird that happened, I went and tried `lmms` - naturally, it didn't start, saying it was uninstalled. So I tried `sudo apt-get install lmms`, and it listed wine1.4 as a package to be installed.

Why does LMMS need wine to run? It seems kind of counterintuitive/silly that ***Linux*** Multimedia Studio needs to be run as if it were made for Windows, not Linux.

**Edit:** My system is fully updated, and here's a picture of my terminal output when I try to install lmms. Note that all the other components, as listed by Uri, are installed completely:
[image]
I also tried `sudo apt-get -f install`, `sudo apt-get clean` and `sudo apt-get autoclean`, and none of those helped.

Comment: No it doesn't the listed packages are:  `caps` `libfluidsynth1` `librtaudio4`  `librtmidi1` `libstk0c2a` `lmms` `lmms-common` `stk`
`tap-plugins` `tcl8.4` and `tk8.4`,  you must have something else installed that requires Wine.

Comment: I posted a picture of what my terminal is showing. My system is fully updated, as well.

Comment: I can only see the listed packages Uri Herrera also sees, when I try to install lmms. Wine is not installed, I am on 12.04 (64bit)... wine dependencies come from somewhere else.

Comment: @mondjunge Yeah, Radu pinpointed it in his answer - it's probably due to VST plugin support, which depends on wine. So I could probably install it without that using the Software Center. (Which I also just noticed you pointed out in a comment on that answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> LMMS supports the native Linux LADSPA plugin specification and the VST/VSTi standard for Windows plugins. (...) **Like all other mechanisms for VST support in Linux LMMS depends on WINE to instantiate those plugins, and WINE's volatility makes it difficult to predict which plugins will run.**

Source: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/introducing-lmms-linux-multimedia-studio

Comment: True, I wanted to point out the same with a link to the compiling specs for lmms: http://lmms.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Compiling_LMMS#Optional_.28but_strongly_recommended.29_libraries , concluding, that you could possibly build an lmms without wine dependency but also without VST-Plugin Support.

Answer (score 1):

Package `lmms` does not actually *depend* on `wine`. Rather, `lmms` *recommends* `lmms-vst-server`, which in turn depends on `wine`, and such recommended packages are treated as dependencies by default.

To install `lmms` [without its recommended packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179060/how-to-not-install-recommended-and-suggested-packages) including `wine`, you may prefer to use:

```
apt-get install --no-install-recommends lmms
```