# Why does Texmaker install Texlive without informing?

Tags: installation, lubuntu, latex

I am using Lubuntu 13.04. I installed Texmaker from Lubuntu Software Center, and it downloaded and installed Texlive without giving the dependency information before installation. Moreover, Texlive is not listed in Lubuntu Software Center. So I don't know what is installed now. Is there a way to get all the installed things listed at this situation? How can I avoid this attitude for further installations and keep my system clean?

Thanks...

Comment: I do not understand why the "software-center" tag is deleted; it is a software-center related question indeed.

Answer (score 3):

By default, packages listed as recommended dependencies are installed along with packages. The `dpkg` [policy manual](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html) describes `recommends` as:

```
This declares a strong, but not absolute, dependency.

The Recommends field should list packages that would be found together with this one in all but unusual installations.
```

See `apt-cache show texmaker` to see the recommended dependencies, including `texlive-latex-extra`. As to the separate question of whether it should be more clear about what is being installed, I suppose this is a policy decision for the relevant software center.

Note that this is different from "recommendations" in the software center.

If you wish to disable installation of recommended packages, see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179060/how-not-to-install-recommended-and-suggested-packages).

Comment: Surely it is unusual that TeX Live cannot be found in the user's repositories?

Comment: TeX Live appears in the Ubuntu Software Center if I search for it, so why it doesn't appear in the Lubuntu one I don't know. Perhaps it is assumed that if you're installing it to use without GUI tools you're happy installing it without a GUI too, but that is pure supposition on my part.

Comment: Lubuntu Software Center seems to be different from Ubuntu Software Center, and it might have some bugs. When I switch to 'Expert Mode' Texmaker disappears while other packages appear.

Answer (score 2):

Software Center is designed to *hide* all technical details from the user. If you want to see them, I recommend to use a different Package Manager frontend, like synaptic, aptitude, apt-get,....