# How to install recommends using gdebi?

Tags: gdebi

Gdebi apparently doesn't install recommend packages by default, it only installs dependencies. I tried

```
sudo gdebi -o="--install-recommends" package.deb
```

but it doesn't work.

How to install also the recommend packages using gdebi?

Comment: Note, that nowadays I'd call `gdebi` deprecated, because `apt` can install from a local file. To make it recognize arguments as local files just prefix the path with either `./` or `/`. So, like, instead of `sudo apt install my_file.deb` you have to write `sudo apt install ./my_file.deb`.

Answer (score 4):

The `-o` option of `gdebi` is not meant to pass command-line options to `apt-get`, but configuration options. Thus, to install recommended packages, you should use:

```
gdebi -o "APT::Install-Recommends=1" ...
```

Since,

1. [`man apt-get`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/apt-get) says:

   ```
   --no-install-recommends
      Do not consider recommended packages as a dependency for
      installing. Configuration Item: APT::Install-Recommends.
   ```
2. From [How to not install recommended and suggested packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179060/how-not-to-install-recommended-and-suggested-packages),

   > The correct syntax in recent versions appears to be:
   >
   > ```
   > APT::Install-Suggests "0";
   > APT::Install-Recommends "0";
   > ```
3. And comment #7 on [this Launchpad question](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdebi/+question/202893#comment-6) says:

   > For anyone googling, I can't give the correct format for APT::Get options, however the following worked for me for APT::Install- options.
   >
   > ```
   > gdebi -o APT::Install-Recommends=0 -o APT::Install-Suggests=0 .....
   > ```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a package manager to install packages, you will have manually gather the depended debs and add them to the command line.  The package manager will respect dependencies, but will only search the packages available on the command line.

Instead of using a package manager to do the installation, it would be better to use a more **A**dvanced **P**ackaging **T**ool that has knowledge of a repository of packages that can be searched for the dependencies and list them on the command line along with the package you desire to install.  This is what apt does for you.  It gathers the dependencies of packages selected to be installed and hands the list over to dpkg.

My solution would be to just run `dpkg -i package.deb` and watch it fail.  Then run aptitude and it will complain about broken packages.  Follow the instructions in *red* at the bottom of the screen and select a solution that best fits what you need.