# How to install recommend packages from a file (package.deb)?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, gdebi

I have a package.deb and want to install all dependencies (Depends field in debian/control) and all recommend packages (Recommends field in debian/control).

Options considered so far:

- Gdebi [apparently](https://askubuntu.com/questions/306245/how-to-install-recommends-using-gdebi) does not support installing recommend packages.
- "sudo dpkg -i package.deb" followed by "sudo apt-get install --install-recommends -f" also only installs dependencies (Depends field in debian/control), but not recommend packages (Recommends field in debian/control).

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to [set up your personal APT repository and install the package with APT from there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/529/how-to-set-up-an-apt-repository).

Another possibility is to extract the dependencies from the package description. This script pulls the `Recommends:` line from the description in the `.deb` file and removes versions and keeps only the first alternative when there are several.

```
apt-get install $(dpkg-deb -I foo.deb |
                  sed -n 's/^ *\(Depends\|Recommends\)://p' |
                  tr , $'\n' |
                  sed 's/[|(].*//')
```

With aptitude, you can install the set of packages matched by a pattern. If there are alternatives, install the one you want first.

```
aptitude install '?reverse-recommends(foo)'
```

From the aptitude full-screen interface, highlight the package, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, navigate to “Recommends” and press <kbd>+</kbd> then <kbd>g</kbd>.

Answer (score -3):

there is a parameter in dpkg named --nodependencies ( that was in earlier days )
today parameter is named - see in man page -

--ignore-depends=package,...
Ignore  dependency-checking  for specified packages (actually, checking is performed, but 
only warnings about conflicts are given, nothing else).

you could try that, but it can be a risk too.

I know only that mostly the risk is not so high. in terminal/konsole :

dpkg -i --ignore-depends=package1,package2,package3...    package-to-be-installed-name.deb