# MonoDevelop reports Build Successful but there is no exe file

Tags: mono, monodevelop

In MonoDevelop, I create a new solution (C# console application).
It gives me a simple hello world program.
I press the run button.
I see "Build Successful"
The terminal comes up and says:

```
Cannot open assembly '/home/beauxq/MonoProjects/cstest/cstest/bin/Debug/cstest.exe': No such file or directory.

Press any key to continue...
```

I look in that bin/Debug directory and it is empty.

The build output:

```
Building: cstest (Debug|x86)

Build started 7/28/2016 9:29:40 AM.
__________________________________________________
Project "/home/beauxq/MonoProjects/cstest/cstest/cstest.csproj" (Build target(s)):

    Target PrepareForBuild:
        Configuration: Debug Platform: x86

    Target GenerateSatelliteAssemblies:
    No input files were specified for target GenerateSatelliteAssemblies, skipping.

    Target GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
    Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because its outputs are up-to-date.
Done building project "/home/beauxq/MonoProjects/cstest/cstest/cstest.csproj".-- FAILED

Build FAILED.
     0 Warning(s)

---------------------- Done ----------------------

Build successful.
```

The same happens when I select "Build" from the menu. "Build Successful" but the directory is empty.

Answer (score 11):

I just stumbled upon this too. Clean, Build, Rebuild all report successful, but nothing really happens.

To fix this, you must install package `mono-devel`, which is also in the recommends tag

> Recommends: libglade2.0-cil-dev, libgtk2.0-cil-dev, mono-devel

Maybe you installed monodevelop with option `--no-install-recommends`, or have `APT::Install-Recommends "false";` somewhere in your apt.conf(.d), as I do.

See also [How to not install recommended and suggested packages?](https://askubuntu.com/q/179060/108339) about recommended packages and `no-install-recommends`.

Comment: This tip helped me out. Using MX Linux 17.1 "Horizon" and first installed Monodevelop using the MX Package installer. After doing  an apt-get install of package mono-devel, my Console app builds an executes fine.

Answer (score 3):

I have encountered the same issue. In my case, all required packages were installed, so I had to look further.

All I had to do is perform a "Clean All" before building / debugging the project.

It was probably due to the MonoDevelop project which was started on a different machine with quite an older version of MonoDevelop.

Hope this might help someone in the same situation.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and couldn't diagnose it via Output category in Project Options because the Output category didn't exist (normally that would say where to create the assembly and what to name it). The problem was that when I created the solution using MonoDevelop, I accidentally chose Shared Project in the Library category (under Cross Platform) which is the default project type for some reason.

To resolve the issue, I created a new solution and chose from one of the project types under "Other" such as from the .NET category, and added my cs files (and resx files--you have to right-click them, and for Build, set to EmbeddedResource, and then change default namespace to same as cs file which calls the resource to avoid missing resource exception). This resolved the issue for me.